# PHP <img> function in str_replace not working

Tags: php

I have this PHP function:

```
$test = "<b>Nice one</b><img src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hJby.jpg'/>";

$test = htmlspecialchars($test);

$test = str_replace("&lt;p&gt;", "<p>", $test);
$test = str_replace("&lt;a&gt;", "<a>", $test);
$test = str_replace("&lt;img&gt;", "<img>", $test);
$test = str_replace("&lt;b&gt;", "<b>", $test);
$test = str_replace("&lt;/b&gt;", "</b>", $test);
$test = str_replace("&lt;/img&gt;", "</img>", $test);
$test = str_replace("&lt;/a&gt;", "</a>", $test);
$test = str_replace("&lt;/p&gt;", "</p>", $test);

echo $test;
```

I tried to run the code. The function for bold text is working. But for the `<img>` it doesn't show the image but the code `<img src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hJby.jpg'/>`

Question, how can I set the image show?

Thanks

Comment: Your question is unclear, it is vague why and what you actually try to do: the first like shows a perfectly valid xhtml markup, so why do you want to modify / process it? What for? I'd say that your further code lines, the string replacements are without any effect, since the original markup does not contain html escaped sequences as you are trying to replace.

Comment: When tried to run the code in web, what I want is the text Nice one is bold <-- OK. and the <img src='http://i.stack.imgur.com/8hJby.jpg'/> display the image. The current now the image is not show, it keep show the code <img src='http://i.stack.imgur.com/8hJby.jpg'/>

Comment: It"s uncler what you are asking, you want to replace <img> with <img>?

Comment: Could it be that your http server does not interpret that PHP at all, but delivers it as literal text? How is the file named that holds that code? Do you have the opening php tag before that code (`<?php`)?

Comment: it shows the image, try from http://phpfiddle.org/

Comment: Simple question, if you try for <b> it is working. and why <img> is not working?

Comment: Sorry guys, I've updated my question. I was missing one function there. Please help to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some line changes;

```
$test = str_replace("&lt;p&gt;", "<p>", $test);
$test = str_replace("&lt;a&gt;", "<a>", $test);
$test = str_replace("&lt;img", "<img", $test);
$test = str_replace("&lt;b&gt;", "<b>", $test);
$test = str_replace("&lt;/b&gt;", "</b>", $test);
$test = str_replace("/&gt;", "/>", $test);
$test = str_replace("&lt;/a&gt;", "</a>", $test);
$test = str_replace("&lt;/p&gt;", "</p>", $test);
```

Comment: Working perfectly. Thanks @yjs

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
$test = html_entity_decode($test);
```

**EDITED:**
Have you tried adding Header on top?

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: Please focus to the $test = str_replace("&lt;img&gt;", "<img>", $test); What I want is the image display... Right now it keep display the code not image

Comment: Your situation is unclear. Provided in $test html `"<b>Nice one</b><img src='http://i.stack.imgur.com/8hJby.jpg'/>"` it totally fine. There's something between your script and browser, that changes output. Try focusing on that. Problem is not in $test value at all.

Comment: Sorry, I was missing one function there. $test = htmlspecialchars($test); I've updated my question. Please help to check

Comment: I've edited my answer, kindly check

Comment: Hi, how about using htmlspecialchars?

Answer (score 0):

`&lt;img&gt;`  cant't match the img tag in your code.
after `<img` there is a blank space, not a `&gt;`

Comment: With or without space, `&lt;` will never match `<`. The replacements cannot have any effect.

Comment: Tried, still no any effect

Comment: the img tag is not a pair. try using `$test = str_replace("&lt;img", "<img", $test); $test = str_replace("/&gt;", "/>", $test);`